# How to display the highlighted item within a list?

Tags: python, scroll, pyqt, pyqt4, qlistwidget

How do I allow my `listwidget` to show the highlighted item upon execution?

Currently for mine, it highlights the item but I have to scroll down every time I execute my program to see if it's highlighting the correct item.. (My list items are very huge)

```
def currentItemSelect(self):
    currentItem = os.environ['ITEM']            
    self.serverItemList.clearSelection()

    for item in self.serverItemList.findItems(currentItem, Qt.MatchFixedString):
       item.setSelected(True)
       serverItemList.scrollToItem(item)
```

I know that `qlistwidget` has a property/slot called `scrollToItem` and I strongly suspect that I have written wrong. Can someone advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i think this should solve your problem .

```
def currentItemSelect(self):
    currentItem = os.environ['ITEM']            
    self.serverItemList.clearSelection()

    for item in self.serverItemList.findItems(currentItem, Qt.MatchFixedString):
       serverItemList.setCurrentItem(item)
```

This seems to do the thing for me.